# Calling noir pages from within the REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, noir

Is it possible to call (or is request the word?) a page defined with "defpage" complete with POST variables in the REPL?

I've created a page with (defpage [:post "/form"] [req] (common/layout ...))

And I would like to see the output of the layout call on the REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [noir.util.test](http://www.webnoir.org/autodoc/1.3.0/noir.util.test.html#var-with-noir) namespace. There are some examples of its usage at the noir [source code](https://github.com/noir-clojure/noir/blob/master/test/noir/test/core.clj)